# Extracting 'parts' of a hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I want to write a function getColor() that allows me to extract parts of a hexadecimal number entered as a long

The details are as follows:

```
//prototype and declarations
enum Color { Red, Blue, Green };

int getColor(const long hexvalue, enum Color);

//definition (pseudocode)
int getColor(const long hexvalue, enum Color)
{
   switch (Color)
   {
      case Red:
         ; //return the LEFTmost value (i.e. return int value of xAB if input was 'xABCDEF')
       break;

      case Green:
         ; //return the 'middle' value (i.e. return int value of xCD if input was 'xABCDEF')
       break;

      default: //assume Blue
         ; //return the RIGHTmost value (i.e. return int value of xEF if input was 'xABCDEF')
       break;
    }
}
```

My 'bit twiddling' isn't what it used to be. I would appreciate some help on this.

[Edit]
I changed the ordering of the color constants in the switch statements - no doubt any designers, CSS enthusiasts out there would have noticed that colors are defined (in the RGB scale) as RGB ;)

Comment: Isn't really __Green__ a middle value?

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rgb#The_24-bit_RGB_representation :

(255, 0, 0) is red
(0, 255, 0) is green
(0, 0, 255) is blue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally:

1. Shift first
2. Mask last

So, for instance:

```
case Red:
       return (hexvalue >> 16) & 0xff;
case Green:
       return (hexvalue >> 8) & 0xff;
default: //assume Blue
       return hexvalue & 0xff;
```

The ordering of the operations help cut down on the size of the literal constants needed for the masks, which generally leads to smaller code.

I took DNNX's comment to heart, and switched the names of the components since the order is typically RGB (not RBG).

Furthermore, *please* note that these operations have nothing to do with the number being "hexadecimal", when you're doing operations on an integer type. Hexadecimal is a notation, a way of *representing* numbers, in textual form. The number itself is not stored in hex, it's binary like everything else in your computer.

Comment: If possible he could also change the enum to enum Color {Red = 16, Green = 8, Blue = 0}. And the switch would become superfluid:
return (hexval >> color) & 0xff

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (Color)
{
  case Red:
     return (hexvalue >> 16) & 0xff;

  case Blue:
     return (hexvalue >> 8) & 0xff;

  default: //assume Green
     return hexvalue & 0xff;

}
```