# separating out color components from an integer in C

Tags: c

Consider a number that represents a pixel of an image. I want to separate it out
into r,g,b component where b is the rightmost 8 bits of the pixel, g is the next 8 
bits.. and so on. How can I separate these 3 values from a given number

Comment: What have you tried so far? Consider looking into bitwise operators

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273264/extracting-parts-of-a-hexadecimal-number

Comment: `red = c >> 16; green = (c >> 8) & 0xff; blue = c & 0xff;`

Answer (score 0):

```c
// Set up
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;
} RGB;

/* Your solution.*/

RGB separate_into_RGB(unsigned int color)
{
    RGB rgb_color = {.b = color & 0xff, .g = (color >> 8) & 0xff, .r = (color >> 16) & 0xff};
    return rgb_color;
}

// Test

int main()
{
    unsigned int test_color = 0x00ffff; // aqua color
    RGB color = separate_into_RGB(test_color);
    printf("%d | %d | %d\n", color.r, color.g, color.b);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Explanation

We are taking the number and shifting its its bits by the desired amount using `>>`
operator so that the bits we need come at last 8 bits.
Then, we use `& 0xff` to make sure than only the last 8 bits are calculated.

#### Edit

As pointed in the comments, you should only use `.r =(color  >> 16) & 0xff` if your color can contain alpha in first 8 bits (which it usually will) and if you are sure that your color is not going to contain alpha in first 8 bits (which is very unlikely), you should remove `& 0xff`.

Comment: There's no need to mask the red value, unless you expect the color value to have high-order garbage, which it shouldn't.  The normal idiom is what I showed in my comment.

Comment: This code works correctly when top byte is used for alpha, so is preferred.